# PHP fwrite and unicode code issue

Tags: php, unicode, ucs2

This is my simple code:

```
$filename = "save1.txt";
    $f=fopen($filename,"a"); 
    # Now UTF-8 - Add byte order mark 
    fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 
    fwrite($f,$content); 
    fclose($f);
```

**INPUT TEXT IN THE TEXTAREA:**

غامضة
شعوذة
مقوس الظهر
قوس
الأثرية
أثري
آثاريا
عالم اثار
علماء الآثار
علم الآثار
ممات

SAVED TEXT IN TEXT FILE:
[image]

**MY REQUIREMENT IS TO SAVE SAME TEXT IN TEXT FILE**

Comment: You may need to `html_entity_decode($content)` first

Comment: html_entity_decode does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

From you text, it's ucs-2 which is also be be directily used by html.

You can use this to trans it to utf-8:

```
iconv( 'UCS-2' , 'UTF-8' , $c );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But sorry, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: what is you issue?

Comment: using iconv output is: ☣ㄵ㤴㬦⌱㔷㔻☣ㄶ〵㬦⌱㔹〻☣ㄵ㜷㬠☣ㄵ㠸㬦⌱㔹㌻☣ㄶ〸㬦⌱㔸㐻☣ㄵ㜷㬠☣ㄶ〵㬦⌱㘰㈻☣ㄶ〸㬦⌱㔸㜻…⌱㔷㔻☣ㄶ〴㬦⌱㔹㈻☣ㄶ〷㬦⌱㔸㔻…⌱㘰㈻☣ㄶ〸㬦⌱㔸㜻…⌱㔷㔻☣ㄶ〴㬦⌱㔷ㄻ☣ㄵ㜹㬦⌱㔸㔻☣ㄶ㄰㬦⌱㔷㜻…⌱㔷ㄻ☣ㄵ㜹㬦⌱㔸㔻☣ㄶ㄰㬠☣ㄵ㜰㬦⌱㔷㤻☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㔸㔻☣ㄶ㄰㬦⌱㔷㔻…⌱㔹㌻☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㘰㐻☣ㄶ〵㬠☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㔷㤻☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㔸㔻…⌱㔹㌻☣ㄶ〴㬦⌱㘰㔻☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㔶㤻…⌱㔷㔻☣ㄶ〴㬦⌱㔷〻☣ㄵ㜹㬦⌱㔷㔻☣ㄵ㠵㬠☣ㄵ㤳㬦⌱㘰㐻☣ㄶ〵㬠☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㘰㐻☣ㄵ㜰㬦⌱㔷㤻☣ㄵ㜵㬦⌱㔸㔻…⌱㘰㔻☣ㄶ〵㬦⌱㔷㔻☣ㄵ㜸㬍